# Django many to many with additional field not working

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and followed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to write my models.py file:

```
class Coin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'coin'
        verbose_name_plural = 'coins'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PublicPortfolioManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PublicPortfolioManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(is_public=True)


class Portfolio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated')
    is_public = models.BooleanField('public', default=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='owner',
        related_name='portfolio')

    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin, through='CoinInfo')
    objects = models.Manager()
    public = PublicPortfolioManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.date_created = now()
    self.date_updated = now()
    super(Portfolio, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class CoinInfo(models.Model):
    coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin)
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    #date_purchased = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)
```

Everything works as it should except when I want to save an instance of CoinInfo, then I get the following error: **table hello_coininfo has no column named coin_id**. I already flushed the database and ran makemigrations and migrate before creating the instances. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: could you add the code you use to save an instance of CoinInfo ?

Comment: I don't have any code for that, maybe that is the problem? Since they didn't use any in the Django docs I thought it was not necessary to write a custom save function.

Comment: Try changing the through to include the app name as well `through='hello.CoinInfo'`

Comment: Including the app name does not work, I still get this error: Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/hello/coininfo/add/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
table hello_coininfo has no column named coin_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with applying the migrations, which caused the coin.id field to be not created in the db and therefore this problem occurred.